# How can I translate this diagram into flat shapes with Photoshop drawing tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, diagram, template

I wish I were skilled enough to figure this out... but it might take me weeks! I need to break down this diagram into 4 accurate individual shapes which can then be scaled up to make a template e.g. all 4 sides of the outer box.

Any tips? I am sure this is not complicated but I just want to make sure I do it right! THANK YOU!

Link to the image

https://www.google.com/search?q=bakfiets+long+dimensions&sxsrf=ALeKk03LU9w_QOc9L42D79pflW83IRno7A:1612882067851&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW3d_1hd3uAhXUesAKHWwMCTwQ_AUoAnoECBMQBA&biw=1800&bih=970#imgrc=7AsUPUOgUqDoNM

Comment: Perhaps photoshop is not the right tool here.

Comment: Drawing with Photoshop tools is a very basic operation. You would get more detailed and thorough help if you reviewed the *help files* for Photoshop. Detailing "how to draw" here would be untenable due to the format. I'd kind of agree with Joojaa though, Photoshop may not be the best tool. And @Vincent it's a google image search link, not  a file link.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Photoshop isn't the right kind of software for making diagrams like that.  Better to use a vector image editor such as Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape (which is free), CorelDraw, etc.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Photoshop isn't the right kind of software for making diagrams like that. Better to use a vector image editor such as Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape (which is free), CorelDraw, etc.  Or if you are trying to make scale drawings or plans, then CAD software might be the best option.